# is returning from ternary statement possible

Tags: php, ternary-operator

In php, using ternary operator in statement i want to return if the condition is satisfied. is it possible to write something like the following.

```
($x > 1) ? return true: ;
```

Comment: No, it is __not__

Comment: `($x > 1)` will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: return ($x > 1) ?  true: false ;

Comment: if it return true. it want to return. else do nothing

Comment: Then you don't want the ternary operator, if you want a simple `if` statement.